# How am I able to access derived class private method?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Below code gives me access to private member function of derived class. As far I remember, private member of a class are not accessible through any means. How is below code is able to access derived class private method?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void function()
    {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    void function()
    {
        cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Base * b = new Derived();
    b->function();
    delete b;
}
```

Output is:

```
Derived::function
```

Comment: Actually you *don't* access the private function, not directly anyway. You access the public function in `Base`, then the virtual dispatch at run-time makes it call the derived function override. It's simply how virtual functions and polymorphism work in C++.

Comment: Access modifiers don't exist at runtime.

Comment: As a sidenote: remember to define a virtual destructor in the `Base` class.

Comment: I modified your sample a bit to illustrate what has been said: [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5c83f8c3b096b38). If you try to call `function()` by a pointer to `Derived` it doesn't compile. (Now, the `private` comes in effect.)

Answer (score 0):

Access control applies to names, not to objects. For example,

```
class C {
private:
    int value;
public:
    int & getValue() { return value; }
};
```

You cannot access to the name `value` but you can access to the object which `value` refers to through `getValue()`.

In the code,

```
Base * b = new Derived();
b->function();
```

you are using the name `function` of `Base` and it is public. So you can access to it. On the other hand,

```
Derived * d = new Derived();
d->function();
```

will be a compile error, because you are using `function` of `Derived`, which is private.